# Является ли последовательность строго убывающей

Tags: c

Уже две недели не могу понять, как решить данную задачу: "Вводится последовательность чисел до первого положительного числа. Определить, является ли последовательность строго убывающей".

Что не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int x1, x2, n, m, s;
    printf("Вводится последовательность чисел до первого положительного числа. Определить, является ли последовательность строго убывающей \n");
    printf("Введите число: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &x1);
    while (x1 < 0)
    {
        x2 = x1;
        printf("Введите число: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &x1);
        if (x1 < x2)
        {
            n = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            s = 1;
        }
    }
    if (s == 1)
    {
        printf("Последовательность НЕ строго убывающая \n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (n == 1);
        {
            printf("Последовательность строго убывающая \n");
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Числа долны вводиться по одному.

Comment: Что, по-вашему, делает этот код (в скобках): `while (x1, x2 < 0)`. Далее, *строго* убывающая - когда следующий **строго меньше** предыдущего... И подряд, а не по парам - глядя на ваш код, похоже, вы считаете, что 2 1 5 2 строго убывающая - ведь 1 меньше 2, а 2 - пяти...

Comment: Ок, я изменил вроде то что нужно. Но как только вводиться положительное число, все равно выдает, что последовательность НЕ строго убывающая, т.е. учитывает последнее число

Comment: @Harry, Что дальше?

Comment: Исправлять новые ошибки.

Comment: @Harry, поэтому я и пришел сюда, потому что я не знаю как это исправить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чувствую, это будет сказка про белого бычка, так что держите:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int x1, x2, strict = 1;
    scanf_s("%d", &x1);
    while (x1 < 0)
    {
        x2 = x1;
        printf("Введите число: \n");
        scanf_s("%d", &x1);
        if (x1 > 0) break;
        if (x1 >= x2) strict = 0;
    }
    printf("Последовательность %sстрого убывающая\n", strict? "" : "не ");
    system("pause");
}
```

Последовательность из одного числа считаем строго убывающей.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: И еще не подскажите, что делает strict?

Comment: Флаг, который просто отслеживает, нет ли хоть одной не убывающей пары. Примерно то, что вы хотели получить с помощью `s` и `n`. Если ответ устраивает - принимайте его ("галочка" слева от ответа) и тем закрываем вопрос...